# Json Deserialization C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a Json string usign Json.NET. I have a basic understanding about it but I've been trying for days and can't make it work, here's my code. (Please ignore any unecessary/extra code, have in mind I was trying multiple solutions based on what I found after researching).

```
public class Location
{
    private string ab_;
    private int c_;
    public string name { get { return ab_; } set { value = ab_; } }
    public int woeid { get { return c_; } set { value = c_; } }
}

public class Trend
{
    private string x_, y_, z_;
    private object a_, b_;
    public string query { get { return x_; } set { value = x_; } }
    public string name { get { return y_; } set { value = y_; } }
    public object promoted_content { get { return a_; } set { value = a_; } }
    public string url { get { return z_; } set { value = z_; } }
    public object events { get { return b_; } set { value = b_; } }

}

public class RootObject
{
    private string o, l;
    private List<Location> list1;
    private List<Trend> list2;
    public List<Location> locations { get { return list1; } set { value = list1; } }
    public string created_at { get { return o; } set { value = o; } }
    public List<Trend> trends { get { return list2; } set { value = list2; } }
    public string as_of { get { return l; } set { value = l; } }
}
RootObject values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString)
```

Now the Json string that im trying to deserialize is this one:

```
 [
   {
      "as_of":"2012-08-31T15:31:55Z",
      "trends":[
         {
            "query":"%23GDTHATXX",
            "name":"#GDTHATXX",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23GDTHATXX",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "name":"#UnMundoEnElQue",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23UnMundoEnElQue",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%23%C3%A7ekicibuluyorum",
            "name":"#\u00e7ekicibuluyorum",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23%C3%A7ekicibuluyorum",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%22Darren%20Kenny%22",
            "name":"Darren Kenny",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Darren%20Kenny%22",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%22Richard%20Wright%22",
            "name":"Richard Wright",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Richard%20Wright%22",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"Yossi",
            "name":"Yossi",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=Yossi",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"Filipinas",
            "name":"Filipinas",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=Filipinas",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%22Javi%20Garc%C3%ADa%22",
            "name":"Javi Garc\u00eda",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Javi%20Garc%C3%ADa%22",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"%22Van%20der%20Vaart%22",
            "name":"Van der Vaart",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Van%20der%20Vaart%22",
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "query":"SSN",
            "name":"SSN",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=SSN",
            "events":null
         }
      ],
      "created_at":"2012-08-31T15:30:32Z",
      "locations":[
         {
            "name":"Globales",
            "woeid":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Twitter.TrendParser+RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

As i said before i have a basic understanding of the Json format, and i've been trying using different types of classes to deserialize with the same result, any tip or any idea about what the problem may be?. I am also stuck with .NET 2.0 and not 3rd party libraries aside from json.NET.

Thank you for the attention.

- EDIT *

Apparently even if i try declaring List value, the variable "value" won't be created in the actual context, any way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array containing one object.

This means that JSON.NET will be expecting single object but getting a list. The error message is basically telling you that.

Give this a try:

```
List<RootObject> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(receiving);
```

Comment: Tried this, it was my fault because i didn't mention it but it says that Values doesn't exist in the actual context, tried initializing it in the constructor and got nothing either. Still tried inspecting it and somehow it doesn't have any value after that. Any idea why?

Comment: Error:  values The name 'values' does not exist in the actual context. I had to translate it as my compiler is in another lanugage but it translates like that.

Comment: That usually means that you are trying to use the variable `values` later on in your code. i.e `values == null` I'd stick a breakpoint after the `DeserializeObject` call and see if you have anything. It does not sound like JSON.NET is throwing the error.

Comment: Done that, apparently it doesn't recognize the variable no matter how i declare it. Maybe it has something to do with the compiler but not sure, i was taking a look at the assembly code and couldn't figure the error either... Weird.

Comment: I finnally managed to make it recognize the variable, but i belive my classes are wrong, or is it that they way the abstract classes have to be declared is not making it work properyl?.

Comment: Are those the most up to date representatives of the classes in your question? When I get the chance I'll have a go at making a little app to test all this. It's tricky doing it in my head.

Comment: dynObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(nvm);
            
            foreach (JObject item in dynObj)
            {
                foreach (JObject trend in item["trends"])
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", trend["query"], trend["name"], trend["url"]);
                    arreglo = trend["name"];

Comment: I used that method and it's working now, i'll how to access each member now =). It'd be interesting if i could make the other method work tho.

Answer (score -2):

`enter code here`/// the classes

public class MambuData
    {
        public mambuData[] mambuDataS { get; set; }
    }

```
public class mambuData
{
    public string encodedKey { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

///the method

private string ParseMambuData(string streamResult)
        {
            string R = "";

```
        List<mambuData> mambuDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<mambuData>>(streamResult);

        foreach (mambuData m in mambuDataList)
        {
           //put data in db if you want

        }

        return R;

    }
```

Comment: How it that related to the question (json deserialization)?

Comment: This solution will not deserialize the JSON data in the original question.